# ios deleteconformation button

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, uitableview

I have a table which has a couple of rows.I have two custom buttons on the cell .One of them is used to delete the row. I am trying to get the delete conformation button which is normally displayed on swipe to delete gesture on the row using the custom button press.

can someone please suggest a solution for the above problem.
thanks.

in short i want to replace the swipe gesture by a button press to make the framework provided delete button appear

Comment: some code- of cell for row method would be better..

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate? It's not clear to me whether you want to replace the behaviour of the regular swipe-to-make-delete-button-appear (and if so, sounds like you might be reinventing the wheel), or if you want to have a swipe just automatically call your own delete button?

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I think you want what's already posted here: [Is it possible to programmatically show the red delete button on a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301728/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-show-the-red-delete-button-on-a-uitableviewce)

Comment: I don't want to replace the behavior . i just want to make the delete button appear on my custom delete button press and not on the swipe.in short i want to replace the swipe gesture by a button press to make the framework provided delete button appear.

Comment: thanks a lot but i had seen that earlier.unfortunately it did not help me much.