# Swipe UITableViewCell without touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swipe

As my title saying I want to swipe first row of `UITableView` left to right when user will come on that `ViewController`.

In my `ViewController` I have one `UITableView`, each row have two button "More" and "Delete" action. Look at below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        // Edit Button Action
    }
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let editButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        // Delete Button Action
    }
    editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return [deleteButton, editButton]
}
```

All is working good. But I want when end-user comes on this `ViewController` at first time so they will notify that there is swipe action available so they will perform it.

**Question is: How can I do swipe left and right automatically for first row ?**

What I have did?

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let cell = posTblView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! POSUserTabelCell
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: -150, y: 0)
    }) { (finished) in
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.25, options: [], animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { (finished) in
        })
    }
}
```

By above code swipe/moving cell is working but not display "Delete" and "More" button.

So please guide me on right direction.

Comment: your approach seems right for swiping left and right. However, i am not sure if the built in buttons could be highlighted like that. What you can do for sure, is to put a `UIView` looking like the native controls below your content, do the swipe to reveal them, and than remove/hide them from the cell. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301728/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-show-the-red-delete-button-on-a-uitableviewce

Comment: You can use this old framework: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell. Then in viewdidappear write:
[cell showRightUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];

Comment: So, what are you aiming for is to let the first row do the swipe automatically, so you can see the edit buttons. Is that right?

Comment: @AhmadF - Yes because some time end-use does not know about this features, they can see only listing if we do like that then they can easily understand that some features available on swipe.

Comment: Here is another solution I used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881375/how-to-move-uitableviewcell-back-and-forth-to-show-it-can-be-swiped/54989879#54989879

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found one way to achieve it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if arrStudent.count > 0 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = tblStudent.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath);

        let swipeView = UIView()
        swipeView.frame = CGRect(x: cell!.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: 170, height: cell!.bounds.size.height)
        swipeView.backgroundColor = .clear

        let swipeEditLabel: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: cell!.bounds.size.height))
        swipeEditLabel.text = "Edit";
        swipeEditLabel.textAlignment = .center
        swipeEditLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)
        swipeEditLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 180/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1) // Light Gray: Change color as you want
        swipeEditLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        swipeView.addSubview(swipeEditLabel)

        let swipeDeleteLabel: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: swipeEditLabel.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: 90, height: cell!.bounds.size.height))
        swipeDeleteLabel.text = "Delete";
        swipeDeleteLabel.textAlignment = .center
        swipeDeleteLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)
        swipeDeleteLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 41/255, blue: 53/255, alpha: 1) // Red color: Change color as you want
        swipeDeleteLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        swipeView.addSubview(swipeDeleteLabel)

        cell!.addSubview(swipeView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.60, animations: {
            cell!.frame = CGRect(x: cell!.frame.origin.x - 170, y: cell!.frame.origin.y, width: cell!.bounds.size.width + 170, height: cell!.bounds.size.height)
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.60, animations: {
                cell!.frame = CGRect(x: cell!.frame.origin.x + 170, y: cell!.frame.origin.y, width: cell!.bounds.size.width - 170, height: cell!.bounds.size.height)

            }, completion: { (finished) in
                for subview in swipeView.subviews {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                swipeView.removeFromSuperview()
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Add custom `UIView` at end of cell and remove it after animation is done.

- You can set custom view's frame as you want
- Add label(s) with background color and title as you want.

Here you should write code for not every time call this code in `viewDidAppear` it should be call once for only user indication.

Comment: I will try your logic hope it will be help me.

Comment: Thanks you so much :) I tried and working perfect as I want. Thanks  agin men.

Comment: @Johnty glad to help you :)

Comment: Good example! but don't forget the set the animation on the main thread to ensure that it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming a cell to the left will not make the action button visible.

You need to send that cell into editing mode by calling the `setEditing` method on the cell, put this in your `viewDidAppear`:

```
let cell = posTblView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
cell.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```